# Загрузка проекта yii2 на VPS сервер

Tags: yii2, vps, hosting

Имеется VPS сервер. проект лежит в папке /home/username/projectname.
Используется шаблон advanced. В настройках сервера установлен путь на projectname/frontend/web. При загрузке сайта ловлю ошибку

> ReflectionException Class yii\web\urlManager does not exist

Из-за чего проблема и как исправить?

Comment: composer update

Comment: @Ninazu в продуктиве только composer install.

Comment: Как угодно. если не находит класс. Либо нет vendor, либо они не обновились, либо не работает autoload. Предположу что проект не разворачивался а заливался по FTP

Comment: @Ninazu да, проект заливался по FTP, но проблему решил.